# Could not find com.facebook.react:react-native:0.72.7

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

i tried to compile my react native app but i have this error:

`FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find com.facebook.react:react-native:0.72.7.
> Required by:
> project :app`

i use: "react": "18.2.0", "react-native": "0.72.7"

my build.gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
   buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33
        ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2')
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

def REACT_NATIVE_VERSION = new File(['node', '--print',"JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(require.resolve('react-native/package.json'), 'utf-8')).version"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim())

allprojects {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            // Remove this override in 0.65+, as a proper fix is included in react-native itself.
            force "com.facebook.react:react-native:" + REACT_NATIVE_VERSION
            force 'com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:0.182.0'
        }
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        maven {
            // react-native-background-fetch
            url("${project(':react-native-background-fetch').projectDir}/libs")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Previously my version of react native was 6.4 and I am trying to update it now it gives me that error

Comment: I'm having the same issue with the Firebase package.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your Kotlin version to the latest. Please check here to see all Kotlin versions. https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/releases

Adding the below line to the dependencies in `build/gradle` will work.

```
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
```

Additionally, looking at your build.gradle file, it seems like you haven't properly updated your project to `0.72.7`. I guess you have to follow this documentation. https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue and kotlin version shouldn't need to defined in build.gradle per the react native docs